# Wait for multiple http requests to finish before running a function in angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, listener

I have multiple http posts that fetches JSON data from a MySQL database. I want a function to listen to all of them and run the next piece of code once all of them returned that data has been received.

I've tried multiple variations of async with await, but the function doesn't appear to wait for the HTTP post to finish.

I've got a risk service risk.service.ts to get the riskTable for instance:

```
getRiskTable(): Observable<Risk[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/getRiskTable`).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        this.riskTable = res['data'];
        return this.riskTable;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

On my Dashboard I call this code:

```
getRiskTable():any {
    return this.riskService.getRiskTable().subscribe(
      (res: []) => {
        this.riskTable = res; // the value is correctly captured here
        return true;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.error = err;
      }
    );
  }
```

And then an async function that runs multiple of these functions, in theory it's suppose to wait until all the functions complete and then log the value. But for some reason the global variable this.riskTable is undefined in this function.

```
async getAllData(){
    let riskTable = await this.getRiskTable();
    let risks = await this.getAllRisks();

    console.log(riskTable); //This returns stuff
    console.log(risks);
    console.log(this.riskTable); //This returns undefined even though it was set in getRiskTable
  }
```

Please any pointers - I am very new to angular and the complexity of this has me completely stumped. 2 Days and 100x variations to get this to work I am slowly losing my bananas!

Comment: You could think about `forkJoin`, which runs all in parallell (if none are dependent of each other), and in the callback you can do whatever you need to do with the data.

Comment: Alright I had a quick look at found and example of forkJoin. They ran it in the service to get all the HTTP requests and then return a result. 

I have multiple HTTP calls that need to remain modular. I would like to call them one by one from various components, and it's for this reason I want the component to be able to access the data from a service and wait for them to finish (in parallel would be ideal but I'll take anything at this point).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off the `async`/`await` keywords are for use with promises, not `Observable`s. So you can convert an observable to a promise using `toPromise()` or you can use rxjs [ForkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). You also need to change the methods to return either an observable or return a promise, you can't do much with Subscription which is what `subscribe` returns when you call it and that is what you are passing now from `getRiskTable`.

One other issue is that you are not taking advantage of the type system, do not use `any` everywhere because these errors could have been caught at transpile time and now you have to guess why it's failing at run time which is more difficult.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

getRiskTable() : Observable<Risk[]> {
  const tableObservable = this.riskService.getRiskTable().pipe(shareReplay());
  tableObservable.subscribe((res) => this.riskTable = res, (err) => {this.error = err;});
  return tableObservable;
}

getAllData() {
  let riskTable = this.getRiskTable();
  let risks = this.getAllRisks(); // should also return some observable

  forkJoin(riskTable, risks).subscribe(_ => {
    // all observables have been completed
  });
}
```

Note that I also added [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) which ensures that multiple subscriptions to the same observable do not result in multiple calls to your API end point. One result is shared between multiple subscriptions to the observable.

Comment: Igor, it's 3am here. I am so damn happy right now I wrote you this little something something:

I am designer
Silly, visual, and
A bit of a whiner

Things got really tough
Thank God Igor came
And gave code love

@_@ !! 10/10 Love you!

Comment: @BrendenEngelbrecht - glad you got it working and I hope it still makes sense in the morning (after you get some shut-eye) :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making use of Angular, you should use RxJS's [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to combine the observables from both api request methods into a single value observable, and return the values by [subscribing](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing) to it.

Do remember to import `forkJoin` into your component.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

..

getAllData(){
  const riskTable = this.riskService.getRiskTable();
  const risks = this.riskService.getAllRisk();

  forkJoin(riskTable, risks).subscribe(response => { 
    console.log(response);
  })
}
```

If you insist on handling it as a Promise instead of handling it as an Observable, you can utilise [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which returns them as a single Promise.

Answer (score 0):

your first function getRisk returns a observable not a promise, you need to do a .toPromise() to convert your observable to promise.
your second function getRiskTable subscribed the observable which is very inconsistent comparing to your first one, you should do the same as your first function only return a promise then your async await should work.

or you can use forkjoin(obs1,obs2), depends on your interest, but stay consistent.